# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found , error in downloaded Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, wamp

Recently i have purchased a Garage Master project code in laravel from code canyon. i copied the source code into WWW folder in C, and edited `database.php`, `.env files` according to my values. then run `PHP ARTISAN command`,it worked.

In my database -> `MIGRATIONS FOLDER only USER and RESETPASSWORD` files was there. After migration my database only had these two tables.[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxKf7.png)

This is the error i got on Localhost when running the app.pls help me out to solve it...

Comment: Looks like you did not follow the installation instructions completely.

Comment: As its paid for code, I would suggest you ask for help from the person that sold it to you

Comment: if you bought this code, doesn't it come with support?

Comment: after downloading a laravel project it's better to run `composer install` and `composer update` . did you do that ?

Comment: Please Contact the Sales Team Where You Have Bought the Product. or Follow the instruction manual. Because They have Build their Own Installation Wizard